# What Linux Distribution is 'Amazon Linux AMI' built on?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

I wonder what Linux distribution is for the AWS LINUX AMI so I used this command:

> $ cat /etc/os-release

The info shows below suggests the Linux distro is Fedora. Why people say Amazon Linux is CentOS?

NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2016.09"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2016.09"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2016.09"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2016.09:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/798427/what-linux-distribution-is-the-amazon-linux-ami-based-on

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Fedora, Redhat, centOs are almost the same thing. See [explain here](https://danielmiessler.com/study/fedora_redhat_centos/#gs.yhIzySk)

Redhat is based on Fedora
CentOs is based on Redhat
Amazon Linux AMI is based on Fedora.

Answer (score 1):

> [Amazon Machine Image - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Machine_Image#Amazon_Linux_AMI)
>
> Amazon has their own Linux distribution based on Red Hat Enterprise
>   Linux. This offering has been in production since September 2011, and
>   in development since 2010.

Comment: Looks like CentOS is a community version of RedHat. So Amazon Linux may not be too far from CentOS/REDHAT.

Comment: https://linux-audit.com/difference-between-centos-fedora-rhel/